# Easiest way to deduce templates

Tags: c++, templates

As an example, I have the following function template:

```
template <typename X, typename Y, typename Z>
void f(X &x, Y &y, Z &z) { ... }
```

I need to write a user interface in the form of

```
void fxyz(std::string optionX, std::string optionY, std::string optionZ)
```

Here, `optionX`, `optionY`, `optionZ` can be `"x1" or "x2"`, `"y1" or "y2"`, `"z1" or "z2"` respectively. Every option corresponds to a different type, i.e., `X1`, `X2`, `Y1`, ... .Currently I implemented it like this:

```
template <typename Y, typename Z>
void fx(std::string &optionX, Y &y, Z &z)
{
  if (optionX == "x1") { 
    X1 x; f <X1, Y, Z> (x, y, z); }
  else { 
    X2 x; f <X2, Y, Z> (x, y, z); }
}


template <typename Z>
void fxy(std::string &optionX, std::string &optionY, Z &z)
{
  
  if (optionY == "y1") { 
    Y1 y; fx <Y1, Z> (optionX, y, z); }
  else {                 
    Y2 y; fx <Y2, Z> (optionX, y, z); }
}


void fxyz(std::string &optionX, std::string &optionY, std::string &optionZ)
{
  
  if (optionZ == "z1") {
    Z1 z; fxy <Z1> (optionX, optionY, z); }
  else {
    Z2 z; fxy <Z2> (optionX, optionY, z); }
}
```

This seems a lot of work especially if there are more template parameters. Any easier way to achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Very few things in C++ have an "easier way". This isn't one of them. The most likely answer is that the existing class design should be refactored and reimplemented in some other way that allows this to be done in a much simpler fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map into `variant`s, then `visit` them.

```
std::variant<X1, X2> choose_X(std::string_view choice) {
  if(choice == "x1") return X1();
  else if(choice == "x2") return X2();
}
std::variant<Y1, Y2> choose_Y(std::string_view choice) {
  if(choice == "y1") return Y1();
  else if(choice == "y2") return Y2();
}
std::variant<Z1, Z2> choose_Z(std::string_view choice) {
  if(choice == "z1") return Z1();
  else if(choice == "z2") return Z2();
}
```

You are not getting out of writing *some* set of rules to get from strings to objects, of course. A possible variation is

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<std::variant<X1, X2>()>> choices_X{
  {"x1", []() { return X1(); }},
  {"x2", []() { return X2(); }}
};
```

Then simply

```
std::string choice_X, choice_Y, choice_Z;
std::visit(
  [](auto&&... xs) -> decltype(auto) { return f(std::forward<decltype(xs)>(xs)...); },
  choose_X(choice_X), choose_Y(choice_Y), choose_Z(choice_Z)
);
```

O(n^2) code length is now O(n) code length (in number of parameters).

Comment: Cool ideas. Learned a lot.